# Why are the Ninja Turtles green?

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

In nature, real turtles are mostly grey to brown, so why are the Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles depicted as green (their skin is colored bright green)?

I expect the answer will be "meta" and not "in-universe" though if I would need to offer an "in-universe" answer I say that the green mutagen ooze colored the turtles green.

**References to turtles' colors (updating list):**

Red-Eared Slider Terrapin:
[image: Juvenile]
[image: Adult]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-eared_slider

Yellow-bellied slider:
[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pond_slider

Green Sea Turtle:
[image]
[image]
Sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Green_Sea_Turtle_grazing_seagrass.jpg
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Green_Sea_Turtle_swimming.jpg

It seems more brown to yellow than olive green.

Comment: To clarify, are you specifically asking why they're green _post-mutation_, or are you asking why they're green, full stop? Because in some continuities at least, potentially all of them, they were probably depicted as having green skin both pre and post-mutation. See [here](https://www.facebook.com/RememberWhenNick/videos/remember-when-tmnt-origin-story/248352355710671/), for example.

Comment: I ask both. Though my explanation above can explain only the post-mutation green-ness.

Comment: It looks like most (if not every) animated shows depict turtles as being green.

Comment: It looks like (from Wikipedia) that the first comics were in black and white and it was the introduction of the toy line when things such as colour coded masks appeared, so it's probably linked to how the toys were produced

Comment: It also seems in most cases the turtles mutant from Red-eared slider terrapins, which are described as green. Another Wikipedia search ("In young or recently hatched turtles, it is leaf green and gets slightly darker as a turtle gets older, until it is a very dark green, and then turns a shade between brown and olive green.")

Comment: There are green turtles IRL. Aquatic turtles also often appear green when you look at them due to the environment, even if they have more brown-ish tones in isolation.

Comment: I checked Wikipedia, and some of the Red-Eared Slider terrapins are olive green when they are hatchling-to-juveniles but most adults are striped black and yellow.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-eared_slider

Comment: After all, it's not easy, being green.

Comment: The plastic figurines range in colour from bright green to muddy brown, presumably so that parents and children could distinguish them

Comment: For the same reason most reptiles/amphibians are depicted as green in animation.  Real world colors have to be simplified for animation.  Blondes have bright yellow hair, redheads have hair like stop signs.  It's just a staple of animation.  If you must have an in-universe explanation, I think the one you cited is the closest you're going to get.

Comment: Looking at [this list of turtle species that make good pets](https://www.thesprucepets.com/types-of-pet-turtles-4788330), a pretty high proportion have skin that looks at least partially green, though they often have stripes or spots of a different color.